# JAVA: buffered reader always gives IOExcepion

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements, bufferedreader

I am reading lines from a file using `BufferedReader`. The code with the issue is:

```
while((line.charAt(0)!='X') && (line !=null))
```

This gives a `NullPointerException when it reaches the last line. However:

```
while(line !=null)
```

alone works perfectly i.e. `BufferedReader` doesn't catch an exception. So, the problem seems to be when implementing multiple conditions with a `BufferedReader` condition.

Comment: check for null BEFORE you check the first char.

Comment: "This gives a `NullPointerException` when it reaches the last line." No it doesn't. It gives a `NullPointerException` *after* the last line. Clearly you aren't checking correctly for end of stream. "i.e. `BufferedReader` doesn't catch an exception": `BufferedReader` is not involved in this exception. *Your code* is involved in this exception. "So, the problem seems to be when implementing multiple conditions with a `BufferedReader` condition" : rubbish. The problem is that you aren't checking the result of `BufferedReader.readLine()` for null. 

"